# run SKAction that follows path while updating animations

Tags: sprite-kit, skaction

I'm using sprite kit.  I need my characters to move along a path while updating animations.  For example, I want to change my run animation to a left facing run animation when my skspritenode starts moving left.

I've tried many combinations of sequences, run blocks, etc, but nothing is working.  Any suggestions.  Pseudocode below:

```
//run initial run animation
//get array of points to move to
//load skactions into an array 
   //upon completion of an skaction re-evaluate which animation to use.
//repeat

//run sequence of SKActions
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are your character constantly running or they just move after user action ?

Comment: They constantly running.  The skspritenode is given an array of coordinates to follow.  That's my difficulty.

Comment: I figured out how to get it to work.  I just used recursion. In my function I just start the animation to run forever, then I perform the first move instruction (skaction) with a completion handle that calls the function again.  I have a static variable that tracks what stage of the movement I'm in.  I access my movement steps from a class property nsarray.  Perhaps there are better ways but this seems to work fine for now.

Comment: I'd like to revise what I said.  Although I was able to run the animation and move command using this recursive call, it had unknown issues.  I'm still curious if  anyone knows how to update animations while running a sequence of skaction move instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured something out.  To clarify what I wanted, I wanted to take a series of points in an array and run them through a function that would move my skspritenode and run animations on it corresponding to the directions my character needed to run.  Here's what I did:

//i and j are int class variables here, don't ask why I had two, but it worked so I didn't change it.

```
    for (;i<len;i++) {
        [actions_array addObject:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(apath[i].x, apath[i].y) duration:1.0]];
        [actions_array addObject:[SKAction runBlock:^(void){
            j++;
//remove the previous action just in case
                [self removeActionForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",j-1]];
                NSArray* frames = [self returnAnimForMoveToPt:CGPointMake(path_to_goal[j+1].x, path_to_goal[j+1].y)];
                [self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:frames timePerFrame:1.0/30.0]] withKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",j]];
            }]];
            }

    [self run

Action:[SKAction sequence:actions_array] completion:^(void){
                //******movement complete, at location*******!!!!!!!!
                [self goIdle];
//other completion handl
            }];
```

Essentially I just run move instructions followed by runBlocks with animations repeatedly. Hope this helps.